# Column matching .csv to database using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, csv, doctrine

I want to import a .csv file with headers such as name, email etc. as part of mail merge functionality in our web app (we are using Symfony 3.4). I have so far successfully managed to persist the .csv file to the database using Doctrine when I know what the headers on the .csv are going to be. I also need to be able to give the user the option of changing the header of  the columns in case the headers are different or auto-matching on import doesn't work.

Is the best option here to persist the information to the database and then move the data using Doctrine, or is there some way to give the user the option to match columns before persisting? I am relatively new to both Symfony and Doctrine so I can't see the solution.

Here is the code from the controller:

```
public function usersListUploadAction(Request $request) {

    //  grab uploaded .csv file
    $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileimplode = implode("/", $file);

    // convert .csv if made on mac
    if (!ini_get("auto_detect_line_endings")) {
        ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", '1');
    }
    //  create associative array from .csv
    $reader = Reader::createFromPath($fileimplode);

    $addedUsers = $reader->fetchAssoc();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    foreach($addedUsers as $row) {
        // check for existing users

        $emailAddress = $row["Email Address"];
        $user = $this->get('manager_user.repository')->findByEmailAddressWithoutParents($emailAddress);

        if ($user === []) {
            //  create new user
            $userTypeId = 1;
            $role = $request->get('roles', []);
            $firstname = $row["First Name"];
            $surname = $row["Last Name"];
            $email = $row["Email Address"];
            $username = (strtolower($row["First Name"].".".$row["Last Name"]));
            $phone = null;

            $userBuilder = $this->get('manager_user.manager')->newUser(        
                $userTypeId,
                $username,
                $phone,
                $email,
                $role,
                $password = null,
                $organisation = null,
                $emailResetPasswordLink = 0,
                $firstname,
                $surname,
                $name = null,
                $roles = []
            );



            $user = $userBuilder;

            // add email to contact_methods
            $cmType = $this->get('manager_user_contact_method_type.repository')->find(ContactMethodTypeInterface::EMAIL);
            $cmEmail = $this->get('manager_user_contact_method.builder')->createNew($cmType, $row["Email Address"], $user, 1);

            $em->persist($userBuilder);
            $em->persist($cmEmail);
        }       

            $em->flush();         
    }

    // return to user list page with list updated from .csv users

    $listId = $request->get('listId');
    $list = $this->get('manager.email.list_repository')->find($listId);
    $status = 1;
    //loop over the added users
    foreach($addedUsers as $row) {
        $userNameLower = (strtolower($row["First Name"].".".$row["Last Name"]));
        $userId = strval($this->get('manager_user.repository')->getUserIdByUserName($userNameLower));


        $user = $this->get('manager_user.repository')->find($userId);

        if(!$user->isInList($list)) { //this user is not in the list already so add it
            $dateSubscribed = new \DateTime();
            $emailCampaignListUser = new EmailCampaignListUser($user, $list, $dateSubscribed, $status);

            $em->persist($emailCampaignListUser);
        }
    }

    $em->flush();


   return $this->redirectToRoute('manager_email_campaign_lists_users_upload_check', array('listId' => 1));  
}
```

Comment: The mapping feature is a good idea but it implies to have one more step before import.
You can easily do this defining expected fields, and printing csv headers.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, could you give a bit more detail about how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provide you an example (not full).
AS i ve commented you can process like this.

1. First step, the user can match **expected** fields with **csv's header** fields
2. Import data using the mapping previously made.

For the **first step**, you can choose the frontend solution you want, like Drag&Drop.

In my opinion you've to define your keys

```
 //this is your code
 //Here we define that "firstname" is your key for the first name
 $fields = ["firstname","lastname"];
```

Second part of the first step is getting CSV header, using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) on the first line (header line)

```
    if (($handle = fopen("yourcsv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
       //Here you get all csv headers
       $header = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","); 
       fclose($handle);
    }
```

At this point after you (or the user) do the mapping, you can store the mapping in database if this is a real need or simply use POST to get the mapping at the second step.

**Second Step** we parse the csv file skipping the first line and use the mapping previously done to get data correctly.

```
 //Your mapping is stored in $mapping by example
  //it contains "fieldname" => "csv index" example "firstname" => 3
  if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  //skip header line here
  fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        //$data contain each user data
        $userBuilder = $this->get('manager_user.manager')->newUser(        
           $data[$mapping['firstname']],
           $data[$mapping['lastname']],
           //etc...
         );
    }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Hope this helps and clear.